# What is the character used by Internet Explorer 10 as the mask in its password inputs?

Tags: fonts, character, internet-explorer-10

I need to know because I want to check whether the primary font has it.  I am investigating why the browser falls back to the secondary font.  My suspicion is that the primary font does not have the character that the browser uses.

Comment: f12>Dom explorer tab, use the find tool to select the password tool. On the rhs of the DT the applied styles are displayed.

the glyph that is used for the password placeholder is inbuilt in the browser, otherwise hackers could read the entered password before it is encrypted and sent to the server.
In IE10 and higher input elements include an input button that users can click to briefly display their password entry.

Web browsers will fallback to a secondary or tertiary font if the primary font is not installed on a machine. See f12>DOM Explorer.